# Is recursive publishing possible / easy in Gradle?

Tags: build-automation, versioning, ivy, gradle

We have an Ant and Ivy-based build management system, which basically consists of a shared ant file and a set of conventions around directory structure.

One hurdle I'm trying to overcome is the fairly common case of "recursive publish". Say, we have 5 in-house code modules that have a dependency graph like this:

[image: Module dependencies]

- Each module should publish its ivy artifacts to our internal repo
- Artifacts not yet cleared for deployment to test should have status "integration"
- Artifacts deployable to test should have status "milestone" (manually promoted by developer)
- Artifacts verified by testers should have status "release"

Say a developer has all 5 modules checked out locally, and has made changes to them all. Now he wants to promote all his changes to "milestone" status. In other words what should happen in the ivy repo is:

- e-1.0-RC1 gets published
- d-1.1-RC2 gets published, referencing e-1.0-RC1 as a dependency
- c-2.0-RC1 gets published, referencing d-1.1-RC2 as a dependency
- b-3.3-RC1 gets published, referencing e-1.0-RC1 as a dependency
- Finally, a-7.1-RC2 gets published, referencing c-2.0-RC1 and b-3.3-RC1 as dependencies.

I haven't found an easy way to do this using ivy + ant (Ivy promises something similar called recursive deliver, but I can't find any working examples of it).

Gradle sounds promising here since it seems to have good support for multi project builds. I did skim through the docs, but didn't immediately find this case as an example. Is there
an easy way to achieve this with gradle?

Comment: Please let me know if the question isn't specific enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I can conceive of this working is with a master build file that propagates version numbers down to the individual build files for each of your modules.  This has the unfortunate side effect of binding your five modules into a unit that would need to be managed as a single entity but it may be the only way to achieve what you're looking for.

Answer (score -1):

That looks like a normal multi-project build to me.  Assuming you are doing a JVM-based language, Gradle has good out-of-the-box support using conventions (you are free to override those conventions to match your projects' needs) - try it and see.

Feel free to ask for more specific detail on a multi-project build using Gradle.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'm looking for the actual gradle command I'd run in order to publish all 5 modules in one step, or at least the specific documentation for this feature.

Comment: @oksayt: I guess you are looking for the [Maven plugin](http://www.gradle.org/maven_plugin.html). The task name you'd need to run it `install`.

Comment: @Benjamin I'm confused why I'd need to use the Maven plugin since I'm not using maven. The `install` task there seems to be more of a workaround for maven's one artifact per module limitation.

Comment: @oksayt: When you say "publish" what do you mean by that? I guess you mean uploading it to a Maven repository and creating the `pom.xml` for it right? If that's the case the Maven plugin is the way to go. Gradle does not support this [functionality](http://www.gradle.org/artifact_management.html) out-of-the-box without applying this plugin.

Comment: @Benjamin I mean publish in the ivy sense: http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/2.2.0/use/publish.html . The solution I'm looking for would use the ivy mechanisms to get the next available version number and publish artifacts.